# how to change a link on different countries on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, internationalization

Is it possible to change the address of a link on different countries?

I am creating a website for a non-profit, and the donations are made through another website(classy).

I have two pages in Classy, one for United States, and one for Canada and the user needs to choose one link to click.

I would like to make the link change automatically if the user is either in US or Canada. Is it possible?

When can I find more information about it?

Comment: You can even change the language of your website so.. I suggest you to grab ip of the users and show the content you defined for that ip range.

Comment: and how do i do that? Sorry I am new to rail. I am using the I18n gem and I could change the link based on locale=en od ca, but how to i get the ip and change the locale over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some functionality which is able to recognize country from IP address, for example [geoip gem](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip) and then make condition which link should be displayed